# Are there any Remote Desktop software with good Multi-Monitor support?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have recently used TeamViewer, which seems to be the only one who can do in a fairly good way, but the pricing is ridiculous.

Both the server and client has two monitors, and the client need to be able to **easily connect to both** and get them both full screen - even though they are not exact same resolution (zoom to fit).

The built in Remote Desktop in Windows is not an alternative, because it changes screen resolution and in that process messes up all windows placement/sizing and is very slow to do so.

So does anyone know any software that will do this? **Please only reply if you have actually tested the multimonitor features and knows it can do what I describe...**

Comment: You might want to add the desktop resolution of both monitors on both PCs if they are different. (Guessing that's why rdp messes stuff up). Also have you tried VNC?

Comment: Doesn't Windows RDC have a "fit session to window" option? That will stop it messing up icon placement.

Comment: One of the monitors is in 1920x1200 while the other 1920x1080. I just want it zoomed out to fit, but RDC will change server resolution causing all windows to be thrown around. I want all open windows to stay exactly where they were like before I connected. I'll look up VNC.

Comment: Composite image showing settings over a Win session shrunk down to silly-small, all without messing up the remote screen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmaQy.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin Strange, that settings is not in the Windows client...
I downloaded VNC, and it just opens a huge window with all monitors. I need my left monitor full screen on left monitor, and right monitor full screen on right monitor...

Comment: Ahh, OK, shame. It's darned useful. I actually only ever remote from Mac to Win, never tried 'inter-Win' so wasn't aware it wasn't there. It does make me wonder why not… but I guess we'd have to ask MS that one ;)